# Can I use K-means clustering labels as my dependant variable for logistic or HB analysis?

Tags: regression, clustering, maximum-likelihood, experiment-design, choice-modeling

## Background

I am investigating Best-Worst Scaling analysis methods.

For those not familiar a survey is presented showing some attributes and the respondent is asked to score 2 of the shown attributes, one as best and one as worst.

A fractional factorial design (BIBD) is used to compute the sets of attributes to be shown together to balance the frequency of each attribute and the frequency of pairs of attributes to capture trade-off data.

## set up

In the dataset the option selected as most is given a score of 1, least is given a score of -1 and those items shown but not scored are given a score of 0.

There are various methods and 'tricks' to derive a dependant y variable for each set of independant x variables such that regression analysis is possible to compute the relative weights or utility of each attribute.

Since we effectively have a sample of observations:

`X = [1,0,-1]` with no `y` value related to each set of `X`.

## questions

I am struggling to understand how to label each observation (set of scores across attributes)

My questions are:

What methods can I use to label each observation?

Naively could I use k-means clustering to label a group to each observation, and within each group compute a logistic regression to find the in-group relative weights?

How would I combine those in-group weights into a whole sample value of the utilities?

Ideally I would like to compute the individual observation utlities and also the global utilities.